# Expiry dates using the state_machine gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, state-machine

I have a model called JobOpportunity and conceptually it can have three states:

- `:open`
- `:closed`
- `:expired`

`:open` and `:closed` are event driven states. Events could be creating the model, or user edits the model. The model is `:expired` when `Time.now` is greater than the model's `.expires_at` property.

With that in mind, is there a way to express this with the [`state_machines`](https://rubygems.org/gems/state_machines) gem?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with state machine. You 'll need cron jobs and/or some logic in your model.